# Smart contract who automatically forwards USDT to an specific address

Tags: smartcontracts, tron

I have deployed a smart contract that simply forwards the USDT it receives to a specific hard coded address, but it is not working. The USDT just stays at the smart contract wallet and does not forward.

I sent 1 USDT to the smart contract and I was expecting to receive it at the recipient address specified within the smart contract, but the USDT remains in the smart contract's wallet. This is the address of the smart contract: https://tronscan.org/#/address/TKdJn8nr5r4btqHNwexMToJ3mQJgVuTU4L

And this is the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface ITRC20 {
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract DepositUSDT {
    address payable public constant exchange = payable(address(bytes20(bytes("TK7pPdxsBiCL36PAtA5uoEUopzsi3tB59h"))));
    address public constant tokenAddress = address(bytes20(bytes("TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t")));
    uint256 public constant tokenId = 1002000;

    constructor() {}

    receive() external payable {
        require(msg.tokenid == tokenId, "Wrong token");
        ITRC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, exchange, msg.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [receive()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#receive-ether-function) function is executed only when the contract receives native token of the network where it's deployed (ETH on Ethereum, TRX on Tron, ...).

But it's not executed when the contract receives ERC-20/TRC-20/BEP-20/... tokens (for example USDT).

Unlike ERC-721 and other newer token standards, the [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) doesn't define any standardized way how to send a hook to a receiving contract. So the absolute majority of ERC-20 contracts (including USDT) does not notify the recipient contract.

---

Having said that, the transfer emits an event log. So you can have an offchain listener (JavaScript app for example) that listens to an event log reflecting the transfer of `USDT` to the `DepositUSDT` address. And then send another transaction that transfers those tokens out of the `DepositUSDT` contract to `exchange`.

One of the ways is to preauthorize another `operator` address to operate all USDT owned by `DepositUSDT`. This `operator` address then sends the transaction to `tokenAddress`, executing `transferFrom(DepositUSDT, exchange, amount)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I just sent 5 TRX but as expected nothing was forwarded. Is there a way to ammend the mistakes or do I need to deploy a new smart contract?

Comment: You'll need to deploy a new contract to a new address... It's often more effective to develop and test your contracts in a local environmen that can forked from a mainnet if you need to interact with mainnet contracts. Example with Hardhat framework: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks